# How to read data in express js from form data

Tags: node.js, express, angular2-routing

Here is request payload I can see in console

```
 ------WebKitFormBoundaryW5j4rbM04jMUgOkU
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="Screenshot from 2016-12-12 18-34-26.png"
    Content-Type: image/png
    
    
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryW5j4rbM04jMUgOkU
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="userId"
    
    12
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryW5j4rbM04jMUgOkU
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="isAdmin"
    
    true
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryW5j4rbM04jMUgOkU--
```

I need to read userId which is there

> name="userId"
>
> ```
>     12
> ```

but my req.body is blank JSON `{}`. how to read this?

**app.js**

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

**routes.js**

```
    var employeeDocumentStorage = multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, cb) {
****//need to read data here**** 
        console.log("uploading");
        console.log(file);
        var x = (JSON.parse(req.body));
        console.log(x)
    
        //var code = JSON.parse(req.body.model).empCode;
        var dest = 'public/documents/vss811/';
        mkdirp(dest, function (err) {
            if (err) cb(err, dest);
            else cb(null, dest);
        });
      },
      filename: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, Date.now()+'-'+file.originalname);
      }
    });
```

Comment: are you using express bodyParser - https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser

Comment: yes i am using bodyParser

Comment: please can you edit your question to show your route, and where bodyparser is initialised

Comment: I have edited please check

Comment: ok, think the problem will be how you're POSTing to the endpoint - can you post your angular / js code that does that?

Comment: Also why are you parsing the req.body there? Can't you simply use it directly?

Comment: `Content-Disposition: form-data` - this won't be parsed by bodyparser. It only handles json and X-www-form-urlencoded. Not multipart

Comment: I am trying different options @Zlatko

Comment: What is the solution of it @Alex

Comment: Need to see your js code where you POST to your url

Comment: @Alex i am using npm for angular 2 https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-uploader

Comment: that will be posting a multipart form which cannot be parsed by bodyParser.

Comment: it's impossible to help you if you don't provide all the details!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Alex has said in comments, you won't get this with body-parser. Your request payload shows that you seem to be using `form-data` content type.

You can use multer to get form-data payloads - and your route already shows you're using multer (`var employeeDocumentStorage = multer.diskStorage({`)):

```
const express = require('express')
const upload  = require('multer')({ dest: '/tmp/' });

app.post('/some-route', upload.single('name'), function (req, res, next) {
  console.log(req.body.userId); // should show 12
  console.log(req.files); // that's your file there.
  // do stuff.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this worked for me

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');
var upload = multer();
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.post('/', upload.none(), function (req, res) {
  // req.body would contain userId
  console.log("Data",req.body) 
  res.status(200).send('OK');
});

app.listen(port);
```